# How to programmatically set the Source Encoding for Jenkins Cobertura plugin

Tags: jenkins, cobertura

We are using Jenkins 1.642.1 and we generate Cobertura reports for both build/deploy jobs and functional test jobs.  (It appears we are using Cobertura plugin version 1.9.6) The generated report includes a link to the js source file which included red/green color coding to indicate line hits.  This file includes non-ASCII characters so garbage chars are rendered in the html view of this file.
When I check the configuration of the build job (which is generated by groovy scripts) the Source Encoding setting for the 'Publish Cobertura Coverage Report' indicates "ASCII" as the setting.  I need it to be UTF-8.  I can choose this manually, but we don't mess with our builds manually.  Everything is generated in CI style - using programming.
In this case, I see the line in the groovy script and it calls 'cobertura [path to file]'.  There doesn't seem to be any room for additional arguments including that for the source encoding.  Can someone point me the right direction to set this value programmatically?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Ah - It appears that you can micro-manage the resulting configuration.xml file via commands in your groovy file like this:
                // Configuring Cobertura 
                project / publishers / "hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher" {
                    coberturaReportFile('Directory path')
                    sourceEncoding(UTF_8)
                }